# Return two rows from SQL table with a difference in values

Tags: sql

iam trying to return 2 rows from table that have a difference in values, not being an SQL wise man i am stuck any help would be appreciated :-)

```
TABLE A:

NAME    DATA
Oscar   HOME1
Jens    HOME2
Will    HOME1
Jeremy  HOME2
Al      HOME1
```

Result, should be 2 random rows with a difference in DATA value

```
NAME   DATA
Oscar  HOME1
Jeremy HOME2
```

Anyone?

Comment: Even better if the code didnt require static entries like HOME1 <> HOME2

Comment: What is your rdbms? Sql Server, Postgres, Oracle?

Comment: Should this question belong on code-golf?  http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couuld be you need

```
select * from my_table a
inner join my_table b on a.data !=b.data
where a.data in ( SELECT data FROM my_table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1);
```

For your code

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[ComputerState] as a
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ComputerState] as b ON a.ServiceName != b.ServiceName 
WHERE a.ServiceName IN ( 
     SELECT  top 1  [ServiceName] FROM [dbo].[ComputerState] 
);
```

Comment: how does this return 2 random rows?

Comment: @devlincarnate  correct .. i have update the answer with random  data

Comment: This returns one row with 2 sets of values in it.  The question asks for the values in two separate rows.

Comment: BY "inner join table b" you mean "inner join table a" as it is same table=

Comment: by inner join b i mean the inner join  with the same table .. exactly .. in sql  the tables are tables .. same or not same are tables .. and you can use them like you explicit in the condition ..

Comment: @dahund scaisEdge called the table `table` instead of `A` as the question outlined it.  So, in this answer, `a` and `b` are just table aliases in the query.

Comment: @ebyrob  correct .... table a mean a is the alias of table .. a.data mean the colulmn data of the table with alias a

Comment: So this ( SELECT data FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1); what is table?

Comment: SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ComputerState]
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[ComputerState] ON [dbo].[ComputerState].ServiceName != [dbo].[ComputerState].ServiceName
 WHERE [dbo].[ComputerState].ServiceName IN ( SELECT [ServiceName] FROM [dbo].[ComputerState] ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) Gives me "Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'."

Comment: @dahund  in this subselect there are not alias so the table is "table".. anyway i have change the answer . with my_table instead of table .. seeem you don't know the alias ..

Comment: I have update the answer setting the alias for your code .. hope useful

Comment: yep  getting there :-) looks better now getting the tables next to each other, but give me this "Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'." if i add "ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1" i maybe should have told it is SQL :-)

Comment: SELECT TOP(1) * and removed LIMIT and order

Comment: @dahund  yes ... is sqlserver and not mysql .. i have update the answer

Comment: Perfect this saves me from alot of C# code, merci :-)

Comment: hey again, is there any chance this could return table in old order? since my dataset now has on row with [servicename, computername, servicename1, computername1]

Comment: i suggest you of post a new question correctly described .. in this way all the community can help you ..

Answer (score 2):

Easy way to have random data.

```
;with tblA as (
select name,data,
row_number() over(partition by data order by newid()) rn
from A
)
select name,data
from tblA
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `where rn <= 2` as the OP wants 2 rows  (or `IN (1,2)`)?

Comment: @Igor No. See `partition by`

Comment: This assume OP has Sql Server.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. @JuanCarlosOropeza - IMO you have to assume something as the OP gives very little information. If the OP wanted a server specific solution they should have included that in their question.

Comment: @Igor I may think the other way, general rule if you assume you are probably wrong. So dont waste your time asking the wrong question. Is better ask for details. Is obvious OP is new user so teach him how make a better question instead.

Comment: There does need to be SELECT TOP 2 however though because the partition is on data and in the example data that would create 3 rows with row_number = 1.  I addition that could end up always choosing the same data combination or preference

Comment: @Matt `newid()` is very good random number generator. ;)

Comment: I know it is and I use it as such too! I was thinking their were 3 distinct values in the data column.  But it is because I wasn't looking at the word data as a column name.... my bad

Answer (score 0):

If the question is really this simple, you can use an aggregate such as `MAX()` or `MIN()` to grab one row for each different `DATA`:

```
SELECT   MAX(NAME), DATA
FROM     TABLE_A
GROUP BY DATA
```

Of course, if any other variables are introduced to the requirements, this may no longer work.

Comment: how is this random?

Comment: @devlincarnate Good point, I read the top part with a focus on simply having different `DATA` values.  If it has to be truly random then this won't work.

Comment: Column 'DATA' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. you know what this is?

Comment: @dahund `DATA` is right there in: `GROUP BY DATA`

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cteA AS (
    SELECT
       name
       ,data
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY data ORDER BY NEWID()) as DataRowNumber
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY NEWID()) as RandomRowNumber
    FROM
       A
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cteA
WHERe
    DataRowNumber = 1
    AND RandomRowNumber <= 2
```

This Expands on @AlexKudryashev 's answer a little.

```
;with tblA as (
select name,data,
row_number() over(partition by data order by newid()) rn
from A
)
select name,data
from tblA
where rn = 1
```

The only issue with what he had Is that the number of Rows where `rn = 1` will be depended on the `COUNT(DISTINCT data)` so it could lead to more than 2 results.  To fix one could add a `SELECT TOP 2` clause but it might not be fully random as results at that point as it will be dependent on the ordinal results of how SQL optimizes the query which is likely to be consistent.  To get truly random add a second random row number and limit the results to the top 2 of those.